# Foreach list of numbers (as array) javascript/jquery alternative to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I've this code for generate a list of numbers mixed from 1 to 20:

```
var cells = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
cells.sort(function(a,b){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*3 - 1);
});
```

Now I need to parse the array for do an action for each number. In PHP I'd do:

```
// PHP loop that I know... I need a javascript equivalent..
foreach($cells as &$cell) {

  // Javascript code, that I need to run
  $(".grid .cell:nth-child(" + $cell + ")").doAction();

}
```

Does someone know how to convert the PHP foreach loop in JS?

Comment: Learning the basics of a language involves a little personal effort. Asking someone isn't an appropriate substitute. Start here [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: Have you looked up for-loops in Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, was a little lapsus, I was looking for the wrong way and I've not thinked about the js way. (I know javascript)

Comment: As you're using jQuery, lxgreen's answer is probably what you were looking for.

Comment: @Boaz: No, lxgreen's answer is an anti-pattern because it's very expensive. You do the DOM selection once, then pick out the individual results.

Comment: @thesystem You're right. Collin Morelli's answer is indeed the better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would really be your best approach:

```
var cellElements = $('.grid').find('.cell'); // Run the selector once, and get all cells

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cellElements.eq(cells[i]).doAction(); // Now just pick from the subset (this is a quick array access)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from `$(".grid .cell:nth-child(" + $cell + ")").doAction();`, you are using jQuery. If so, you can use `$.each` iterator that jQuery exposes.
For example, you can do something like this:

```
    $.each(cells, function(index, value){
        $(".grid .cell:nth-child(" + value + ")").doAction();
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Future readers, don't use this approach. There are much more efficient ways to do this. Yet another answer that shouldn't be used gets multiple votes on StackOverflow.

Comment: @thesystem The OP and the voters seem to concur. It seems sometimes the system actually works :)

Comment: @Boaz: Glad to see OP changed the accepted answer. Bad practices spread far too quickly.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I just didn't consider the performance, and related to the 'foreach' part. The selector should be processed once, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

standard for loop will work fine for this as a comparison to the php code although is inefficient.

```
for(i=0; i<cells.count; i++) $(".grid .cell:nth-child(" + i.toString() + ")").doAction();
```

Comment: @thesystem Agreed, this solution runs the selector multiple times and would not be efficient at all.

Comment: @JAAulde: The selector is in a loop. Is it unclear that the selector is being run multiple times?